# What is the difference between the Client and GTK versions of emacs?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-10.04, gtk

My Ubuntu 10.04 desktop has three versions of emacs:

1. emacs-snapshot (client)
2. emacs-snapshot (GTK)
3. GNU Emacs 23

I mostly use `emacs-snapshot`, but I also use regular emacs in terminal mode `emacs -nw`. However, it is not clear to me what the difference is between the client and GTK versions of `emacs-snapshot` is, which one is launched by `emacs-snapshot` at the terminal, and if I should uninstall one or just ignore it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emacs-client will edit your files in already running emacs. So if you set the environment  variable $EDITOR to emacs-client, and have an already running emacs, then every program that want to edit a file will use the already running Emacs.